# Location of sphinx-build on CentOS

Tags: centos, sphinx, centos6

I have a brand new CentOS 6 box and wanted to install sphinx, in order to compile documents as generated by readthedocs.org i.e. rst files.

In a previous ubuntu box I was running

```
make html
```

and that would invoke the

```
sphinx-build
```

command and compile the documentation.

I downloaded the latest version of sphinx and installed it as such:

```
sudo wget http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.1.9-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
sudo localinstall sphinx-2.1.9-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

Everything seems to be fine but `sphinx-build` is nowhere to be found.

Any pointers are more than appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up two different tools named Sphinx: the full text search server (http://sphinxsearch.com/) and the documentaton generator (http://sphinx-doc.org/). You need the latter tool in order to compile documents using`sphinx-build`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also install rpm package of sphinx (Python documentation generator) with yum at CentOS 6 using:

```
yum install python-sphinx.noarch
```

at Fedora 20 using:

```
yum install python-sphinx-doc.noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

A short addup, according to [offical document](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/tutorial.html), one just need to run
`pip install Sphinx` to install the python documentation generator, sphinx. Or it can be downloaded from distribution package.