# OS X install of Sphinx: The 'sphinx-build' and 'sphinx-quickstart' not found

Tags: python, macos, python-sphinx

There have been several 'unanswered' postings on this topic pertaining finding 'sphinx-build' not being able to be found:
[sphinx-build -h command not found in Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582037/location-of-sphinx-build-on-centos)

Sphinx was installed upon OSX using both:

- `python3 -m pip install sphinx`
- `brew install sphinx`

In either case, both commands `sphinx-build` and `sphinx-quickstart` cannot be found.

Even though `python3 -m pip freeze` shows installation:

```
Sphinx==1.3.6
```

What am I missing?

Thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar issue after installing sphinx on OS X El Capitan. I installed sphinx using pip: `pip install sphinx --user`. Despite the `sphinx-build` binary existing in `~/Library/Python/2.7/bin`, the command could not be found.

The issue was that I had path set to `PATH="~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"`. Replacing the tilde `~` with `$HOME` so that it was `PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This doesn't work if python was installed with homebrew, and the question does contain `brew install ...`, but its not explicit.

Answer (score 30):

For homebrew, the tools seem to be in `sphinx-doc` nowadays. And it's not by default put in your `PATH` either because `sphinx-doc` is "keg-only". To install it and get it into `PATH`, you can do:

```
brew install sphinx-doc
brew link sphinx-doc --force
```

For full disclosure to the reader, I will include the keg-only warning brew emits when `--force` is not used:

```
Warning: sphinx-doc is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.
```

I don't know why `sphinx-doc` is keg-only, but putting `sphinx-{quickstart,apidoc,autogen,build}` in `PATH` seems harmless to me.

Comment: I believe the reason that it gives you that warning is because `pip3 install sphinx` *also* wants to write to /usr/local/bin/spinx-apidoc` and so on. For example if you do `brew install sphinx-dox; pip3 install breathe;` the latter will fail because it tries to do `pip3 install sphinx` and can't overwrite `/usr/local/bin/sphinx-apidoc`. Although I guess the correct solution in this case is to uninstall brew's sphinx.

Comment: Although... now that I did that, `pip3 install sphinx` doesn't actually write to `/usr/local/bin/sphinx-apidoc`. It must have tried to do something else to it (I got a permission denied error).

Comment: After running `pip3 uninstall sphinx; pip3 install sphinx` all of the `sphinx-build` etc. scripts showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of [@Dan Murphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2793226/dan-murphy)

My installation of python 3.4 was at root. Modified `~/.bash_profile` as follows:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used homebrew to install Python the paths are slightly different. Here is what I hope is a **general method for resolving this problem**:

- Run `python3 -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))'` and look for some lines like `.../Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/...`.
- There will be a `bin/` that is a sibling of `lib/`. That `bin/` contains `sphinx-quickstart` and the other sphinx commands.
- For homebrew installed python3 on osx the directory should be `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin`
- Put `export PATH=$PATH:.../Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin` in your bash profile and restart your terminal.

Comment: I couldn't find anything sphinx-related anywhere in that folder unfortunately. In fact `pip3 uninstall sphinx` lists all the files it will remove and there is no `sphinx-build` anywhere.

Comment: Weird - I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and the second time it correctly added scripts in /usr/local/bin

Comment: > *There will be a bin/ that is a sibling of*, I don't know what this is referring to, where is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

For new users, installing with brew gives the following caveats:

```
==> sphinx-doc
sphinx-doc is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this formula is mainly used internally by other formulae.
Users are advised to use `pip` to install sphinx-doc.

If you need to have sphinx-doc first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/sphinx-doc/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Running the echo command:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/sphinx-doc/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

should fix the issue.

Don't miss `source`-ing the .zshrc after the updating it:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```